# Why does Chome choose the wrong video codec in webrtc connection?

Tags: webrtc

So I have two peers, Alice and Bob.  Alice wants to receive video from Bob but not send her own.  Bob does not support VP8/9, only h.264.  Currently the webrtc connection is established without errors, but Alice sees a purple mess for video.  The video displays correctly after modifying the offer m line.

In more detail.. Alice creates an offer with the following m line and sends to Bob.  Stream ids 96 - 101 use vp8 or vp9 codecs.  ids > 101 use h.264.

```
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 114 115 116
```

Since Bob does not support vp8 or vp9, his answer contains the following m line:

```
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 114 115 116
```

Alice receives the answer from Bob, calls setRemoteDescription, then gets the ontrack callback, and then the setRemoteDescriptionFinished callback.

I would expect Alice’s browser (Chrome 79.0.3945.130, Mac) to choose 102 and use an h.264 decoder.  The purple, garbled video looks suspiciously like video data being decoded by the wrong decoder.

So as an experiment I removed the entries in the 96 - 101 range from Alice’s offer before setLocalDescription and before sending to Bob.  With this change the video displays correctly.

Does someone more knowledgable about webrtc have any idea what might cause Chrome to choose a stream not present in the peer answer?

I am in the process of testing this on other browsers and simplifying the code for more testing.

Also worth noting is that only the offer passed to setLocalDescription needs to be modified.  If the unmodified offer is then sent to Bob, video is still displayed correctly.

According to webrtc-internals, Alice's Chrome is indeed selecting 96 (VP8) as the format of the inbound-rtp stream, even though it is H264.

Comment: what is the profile-level-id and packetization-mode in the fmtp line? Purple and garbled sounds like something is being decoded but not correctly. In chrome://webrtc-internals on the inbound-rtp stream what is the decoderImplementation?

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out inbound-rtp!  I don't know how I missed it.
Without the SDP modification Alice (Chrome) shows decoderImplementation is libvpx.  Also, from the codecId and [codec] entries I see it is indeed selecting 96 (VP8).  Modifying the m line before setLocalDescription results in 102/H264 and decoderImplementation = ExternalDecoder.

Comment: that sounds like you're doing the munging in a way that is interestingly wrong. Do you have a chrome://webrtc-internals dump?
Also instead of munging try setCodecPreferences shown in https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/web_tests/external/wpt/webrtc/RTCRtpTransceiver-setCodecPreferences.html?q=setcodecpreferences+wpt&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=3

Comment: Sorry, I got distracted.  setCodecPreferences sounds like an excellent suggestion.  I'll look into it and report back.
I didn't realize "munging" was discouraged.  I see it recommended often.

Comment: Does anyone know if you can also do this with a codec it does not include in the initial SDP, but you know is supported?